# How to complete my stripe payment with symfony and intent payment API?

Tags: php, api, symfony

I try to put stripe on my website, it takes the payment but it still incomplete be cause "the customer doesn't have payement methods". I dont understand how to resolve this issue.

```php
public function stripeAction(Request $request) {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_UYs0lRfiKXpBymFf0Qlp2BOe00c5XJG5q1');
    $paymethod =  \Stripe\PaymentMethod::create([
        'type' => 'card',
        'card' => [
            'number' => '4242424242424242',
            'exp_month' => 2,
            'exp_year' => 42,
            'cvc' => '424',
        ],
    ]);

    //    dd($paymethod['card']['checks']);

    $intent =  \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => 500,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        "payment_method_types" => ['card'],
        'metadata' => ['integration_check' => 'accept_a_payment']
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems quite straightforward to me: you've create a `PaymentIntent`, without a `payment_method` property. As you also didn't set a `customer` property (which could imply a preferred `payment_method`), Stripe does not know which payment method to use for the intent.

```php
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => 500,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'metadata' => ['integration_check' => 'accept_a_payment'],
    'payment_method' => $paymethod->id
]);
```

Docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-payment_method